# How to limit genres for each comic in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

**App/Models/Comic.php**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use App\Models\Genre;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    
    class Komik extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $guarded = ['id'];
        
        public function genres()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class);
        }
    
    }
```

**KomikController**

```
   public function terbaru(Komik $komik)
    {
        $komikTerbaru = $komik::with(['genres'])->take(6)->get();
        return response()->json($komikTerbaru, 200);
    }
```

I have two table komik and genres, where a komik has many genres and i would like to retrieves 6 latest komik from database, but when i do that with code above, it will return all genres from each 6 latest komik data.

what i want is limit the genres return by 2 for each latest komik(6) returned, how can i do that in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function terbaru(Komik $komik)
{
    $komikTerbaru = $komik::with([
        'genres' => fn ($query) => $query->limit(2)
    ])->take(6)->get();

    return response()->json($komikTerbaru, 200);
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads for reference

Comment: This query return two genres from all latest komik not two from each latest komik, what i want is to return two genres for each latest komik